# Joining to landing pages query doubles the sessions per source

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query sum of visits per source from a Big Query table of Google Analytics data, but will need to filter some sessions out at landing page level. Hence I'm pre-querying visitIDs by landing page and re-joining to session data like so:

```
#StandardSQL
WITH landingpages AS (
  SELECT
    visitID,
    h.page.pagePath AS LandingPage
  FROM
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
  WHERE 
    hitNumber = 1
  AND
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20150926' AND '20150926'
  # filters to be added here
)

SELECT
  sessions.trafficSource.source,
  SUM(sessions.totals.visits) AS visits
FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS sessions

JOIN 
  landingpages
ON
  landingpages.visitID = sessions.visitID
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20150926' AND '20150926'
GROUP BY
  trafficSource.source
ORDER BY
  visits DESC
```

This roughly doubles the number of sessions per each source as reported from GA.

Can anyone point out what I've done wrong? (I suspect it is blindingly obvious)

I've tried examining the data output from the first query and can't find anything wrong with it aside from a very small proportion of duplicated visitIDs. I've also tried various different types of JOIN, all to now avail.

Comment: I can see where I've gone wrong, I neglected to follow the advice I'd already been given http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894328/select-revenue-per-landing-page-for-nested-table-using-google-big-query. It hadn't fully permeated that a unique visit is represented by a fullVisitorID and visitID and a double join is required. Working on verifying this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying ga data from GBQ it's imperative to know and keep in mind that a unique visit is represented by both a fullVisitorID and visitID. Only a double join on both will return a meaningful data set.

Here's what I should have written:

```
#StandardSQL
WITH landingpages AS (
  SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    visitID,
    h.page.pagePath AS LandingPage
  FROM
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
  WHERE 
    hitNumber = 1
  AND
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20150926' AND '20150926'

), 
session_data AS (
   SELECT
      date AS ga_date, trafficSource.source AS source, fullVisitorId, visitID, SUM(totals.visits) AS visits
    FROM
      `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20150926' AND '20150926'
    AND
      totals.visits > 0     
    GROUP BY ga_date, source, fullVisitorId, visitID
)

SELECT 
  ga_date, source, SUM(visits) AS Sessions
FROM 
  landingpages 
JOIN 
  session_data
ON 
  landingpages.VisitID = session_data.VisitID 
AND 
  landingpages.fullVisitorId = session_data.fullVisitorId
GROUP BY 
  ga_date, source
ORDER BY
  Sessions DESC
```